# Plotly JS: hover event does not contain points

Tags: javascript, hover, plotly

I need the x-axis values, when hovering over my plotly chart.
According to the plotly docs (https://plot.ly/javascript/hover-events/) the hover event callback should contain the field "points" from which I should get the x value.

But if you look at this basic example you can see that the callback does not contain the field "points". Also other fields like "data" are undefined:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var tester = $('#tester');

   tester.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
     console.log(data)
   });

   Plotly.plot( 'tester', [{
       x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], { 
       margin: { t: 0 } } );
})
```

See this fiddle in order to try it yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/c1kt3r82/158/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `plotly-basic` does not seem to support hover events, use `plotly-latest` instead
- when using jQuery to select the element, it returns a different object than doing it via `document.getElementById`
- the `hover` events need to be defined after calling `plot`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tester = document.getElementById('tester');

  Plotly.plot(tester, [{
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
  }], {
    margin: {
      t: 0
    }
  });
  tester.on('plotly_hover', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! :)